# How to get char from a Byte ASCII value in Codesys

Tags: hex, ascii, codesys

Good morning,

I would like to get the char which corresponds to a ASCII code. For example, if I have a byte with a value 16#68, I would like to get a char with value 'h'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Codesys 3.5

```
VAR
    someByte: BYTE := 16#68;
    theChar: STRING(1);
END_VAR
```

`theChar[0] := someByte;`

[image]

A STRING is just an array of BYTES. You can replace any of them with whatever value you want.

#### Alternatives:

```
VAR
    someByte: BYTE := 16#68;
    theChar: STRING(1);
    bytePtr: POINTER TO BYTE := ADR(theChar);
END_VAR
```

`bytePtr[0] := someByte;` or `bytePtr^ := someByte;`

#### Or

Create a Union:

```
TYPE CHAR :
UNION
    ascii: STRING(1);
    raw: BYTE;
END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

`theChar.raw := 16#68;`

[image]

Comment: I am using Codesys 2.3 and I got following message:https://ibb.co/1MgqLcK . What is wrong?

Comment: Personally, I haven't worked with 2.3, but I see no reason why the 2 alternatives wouldn't work